# Android: Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, twitter-fabric

I know that there are a million other questions on OutOfMemoryError on SO. But my case is different. None of the lines in the stack trace is from my code or a library that I have included. Whole of the stack trace consists of Android's standard libraries.

I don't have any clue as to where I should start my debugging. Any ideas on how I should debug it further?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:196)
       at android.util.ArrayMap.ensureCapacity(ArrayMap.java:307)
       at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:247)
       at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Are you using an array that has more index than its size in your app?

Comment: Start by obtaining a heap dump when it runs out of memory. Then inspect that and see what objects you have using the memory. Find what objects should not still be alive and then fix your code so it doesn't keep a reference when it shouldn't.

Comment: Check, too, that you aren't leaking activities or fragments through inner classes.

Comment: @dsh - I see this crash on Fabric console(btw, they just got acquired by Google today). And I donot have access to the phones on which the crash is happening.

Comment: How do I pin point leaking activities or fragments? Leak Canary only points to class members rather than the activities themselves.

Comment: That is very relevant information.  I know nothing about fabric, so I can't help in that regard.

Comment: The stack trace you have shows only the last allocation that was attempted when you ran out of memory. It may not be the real problem. That allocation happened as the system tries to restore ("unparcel") an array that was saved in a fragment's "bundle".

Answer (score 0):

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
  android:largeHeap="true"
```

Adding largeHeap might be fix it